# Is there a Firefox shortcut to copy the URL of the current page?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Copying the URL of the current page seems to be an extremely common task, and I can't seem to find one in the official list. Are there any tweaks or add-ons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Worth pointing out that CTRL+L doesn't work in IE. Use ALT+D instead.

Comment: Or, on MacOS X: Command-L followed by Command-C.

Comment: @happy_soil: worth pointing out that not working in IE is not uncommon for Firefox shortcuts ;-)

Comment: @Jonathan: what about on Macs with CTRL labels pasted onto the Command keys?

Comment: @msw: that's a bit like asking "if you call a tail a leg, how many legs does a dog have?"...

Comment: f6 instead of CTRL+L saves a keypress. And does work in IE for @happy_soil

Comment: F6 will also work besides ctrl+L and alt+D

Answer (score 2):

Try [URLBarExt](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8758/) add-on.  I use it all the time to copy the current URL or make it small using one of several URL shorteners.